# Issues with Click to Call event tracking code

Tags: javascript, html, google-analytics

I actually pulled this code from stack overflow and it doesnt seem to be registering in analytics for click to call event tracking:

```
<a href="tel:18002514391" onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'Phone Call Tracking','Click/Touch','Header');">
1.800.251.4391</a>
```

I have checked and everything matches where it should in the goal setup in GA.

I am wondering if this part is messing it up? Here is the full code:

```
<div id="Phone_Button">
            <p><a href="tel:18002514391" onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'Phone Call Tracking','Click/Touch','Header');">
1.800.251.4391</a>
</p>        </div>
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Are there any errors in the browser console?

Comment: Are you including the analytics code after this link perhaps?

Comment: When I check for errors in console i get "uncaught syntax error: unexpected token <"

The red X is after the <div id="phone_Button"> X

I feel silly but i am still not sure how to fix it, but I had a feeling it had to do with this area, the "phone button" isnt even a button I am not sure why it is labeled as such. That part is not my code so I dont want to pull out any formatting if I dont have to.